# How to take count some data of a file which is in archived folder?

Tags: linux, awk, tar, wc

I have a archived folder which contain some files, from one of those files I want to take count of 31 delimiter. How to get count without unzipping folder?

archived folder name =mug.tar, file name = APR_17

Below is how to take count

```
| awk -F "|" '{print $31}'|grep "40411"|sort -n|uniq -c|wc –l
```

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) you can get a quickstart of the most simple, most important basic spelling rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untar the wanted file from the archive file to stdout and pipe it your awk:

```
$ tar -xOf mug.tar APR_17 | awk ...
```

`man tar`:

```
 -x, --extract, --get
       extract files from an archive

 -O, --to-stdout
       extract files to standard output

 -f, --file ARCHIVE
       use archive file or device ARCHIVE
```